# What is a camera app for the iPod touch geared towards filming video?

Tags: software-recommendation, ipod-touch, camera

I know that there are several camera apps for iOS, but what's a good one for the iPod Touch? More specifically, I'm looking for an app for taking good video.

Comment: How would you define "good", especially compared to the builtin Photo/Capture app?

Comment: I am looking for an app that is geared more towards taking video. More features for taking video...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need more control over the video I'm recording I use [Canopy Camera Tools](http://itunes.apple.com/be/app/canopy-camera-tools/id417407454?l=nl&mt=8). The Canopy app lets you choose a separate focus and exposure point - unlike the stock Camera app. It also lets you lock the white balance once you found a good exposure. Those features are also available when you want to take a picture.
You can also make time-lapse video's with Canopy.

I'm sure there are alternatives to Canopy but this is the app I use.
There are also apps that - unlike the stock Camera app - let you zoom while you're recording a video but since any zooming is achieved through digital zoom and not optical zoom they will degrade the quality of the video.

Answer (score 1):

[Capture](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id442879059?mt=8) is handy. Launching the app starts recording and quitting the app stops recording. Admittedly less useful now that iOS 5 has the camera shortcut on the launch screen, but it's nice for when you want to launch directly into video recording mode.